# Efficient way of changing background color of an element in CSS3 or HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change each item's color in a list after a reorder or removing one item, now I am using jquery's css method like below

```
$('li').css('background-color', color);
```

It works, but terribly slow, and sometimes the page will render the color incorrectly, even on Chrome, which is supposed to be fast. The list doesn't have many items, below 10, usually 5 - 7. So this performance is not acceptable. So I want to know if there is a better, faster way in CSS3, or HTML5. If not, if there is an walkaround or some kind of jquery solution?

The code for refreshing list items' color is as below. The index can be decided by a function and the color can decide color by it. The major issue I think is that changing background color trigger reflow or maybe rerendering.

```
function refreshListItemColor(liElements, colorGetter, indexGetter) {
        colorGetter = colorGetter || (function (color) {
            return color;
        });
        indexGetter = indexGetter || (function (liElement, index) {
            return index;
        });
        liElements.each(function (index, liElement) {
            index = indexGetter(liElement, index);
            var data = ko.dataFor(liElement);
            var indexColor = colorForIndex(index);
            indexColor = colorGetter(indexColor, data);
            if (indexColor !== $(liElement).css('background-color')) {
                $(liElement).css('background-color', indexColor);
            }
        });
}
```

**Update**: using element.style['background-color'] won't do. The issue still remains. Another possible explanation for the lagging is that every list item itself has about 10 child elements, making change list item's color particularly expensive.

**Update2**: I'll try to ask a related question: is there a way to change the color of the background of the parent node without triggering a rerender of children elements?

**Update3**: I tried to add delay for each color change operation, like below

```
var delay = 100, step = 100;
liElements.each(function (index, liElement) {
    index = indexGetter(liElement, index);
    var data = ko.dataFor(liElement);
    var indexColor = colorForIndex(index);
    indexColor = colorGetter(indexColor, data);
    if (indexColor !== $(liElement).css('background-color')) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            liElement.style['background-color'] = indexColor;
        }, delay);
        delay += step;
    }
});
```

It seems can alleviate this issue a lot. I guess this will not solve the problem, but will reduce the impact to an acceptable level.

Comment: can u share some of ur code..to help u...

Comment: It is fast for me. “Slow” is subjective. You should not be able to see a delay, if it really is a small list and HTML document. Also, I do not get how slowness could ever lead to false color rendering. If you really see unexpected colors, you have a different problem as well.

Comment: Given your additional code, as you do not use `$('li')` as an expensive selector, but instead `$(liElement)` witha dom object directly it seems, the element selection is not your performance problem. And neither is the setting the background via `.css`.

Comment: As you can see from the update question (I added source code), there is nothing fancy here, but I do see slowness and false rendering.

Comment: hi, @Kissaki, the color changing part is indeed the performance problem, if I remove the the line - $(liElement).css('background-color', indexColor); - then I have no performance issue anymore

Comment: I am not sure how your question can be asked directly. The title question can be answered with the `.css('background-color', color);` you named *is* an efficient way to set the CSS background (ofc your could use plain JS instead of jQuery). Your actual (performance) problem is now more of a support issue it seems. I'd pull out the in-browser profiler now and see which steps consume most CPU. Did you try that?

Comment: maybe I should not use jquery and use element.style['background-color'] instead?

Comment: Oh really? Can you provide a jsfiddle with some (minimal) HTML, CSS and JS, so we can work with it?

Comment: jsfiddle would be a little overkill since I am using gridster library, the issue rises only from using it together with drag animation combining the color changing. I guess gridster is doing some heavy work in the background, but I cannot change that, at least not easily. Hence I want to have an efficient way of changing background color. If I don't gridster, then no noticable performance  issue

Comment: using element.style['background-color'] won't do. The issue still remains.

Comment: As this lengthy comments discussion shows with new details raising up again, your question was (and still is) missing essential details. If you can not provide a good enough simple example I would still say, try to use the profiler yourself. No idea what you mean with "drag animation combining the color changing". But after your recent comment I'd blame gridster.

Comment: I blame it too, but it's just not possible for me to change it to make it more efficient since it must be very time-consuming and error prone. As for your suggestion of using profiler, I'll try that.

Comment: Just for fun, see if this works -> http://jsfiddle.net/LwuyW/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) in your stylesheet?

```
[data-row="1"][data-col="3"]{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

I noticed that If you want to select a whole row or column you have to use `!important`

```
[data-col="3"]{
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

[image: css change]

---

**(edit)Adding styles dynamically**
Create a empty style tag with a div

```
<style type="text/css" id="dynamicstyle"></style>
```

and just append to it like any other tag

```
$("#dynamicstyle").append('[data-row="0"]{background-color:red !important;}');
```

for your case you can check whenever an element is added and add a row style since in theory the user could pile up all of the elements.

```
$(function () {
var maxRows = 0;
$("ul").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", updateStyleSheet);

function updateStyleSheet() {
    var childCount = $("ul").children().length;
    if (maxRows < childCount) {
        maxRows = childCount;
        var newRule = [
            '[data-row="',
        maxRows,
            '"]{background-color:', ((maxRows % 2) ? "red" : "blue"),
            ' !important;}'].join('')
        $("#dynamicstyle").append(newRule);
    }
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PgAJT/126/

FizzBuzz rows http://jsfiddle.net/PgAJT/127/

Comment: No. I cannot, since there can be a lot of rows, and user can add or delete an item in the list. But this is a great answer though. Is there a way to add css sytles dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

Remove your "if", which may force browser to redraw/recompile/reflow latest CSS value.

```
if (indexColor !== $(liElement).css('background-color')) {
```

Yes, read are slow and as they will block write-combine.

Comment: This is actually fine since originally, there is no if statement, but still slow. So although this is a good suggestion, it won't solve the issue

Comment: do you access ANY dom element attribute in your indexGetter and colorGetter ?

Comment: I do access DOM element in the colorGetter and indexGetter, but that dom element is passed in to colorGetter and indexGetter, I just use jquery attr method, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the colour is determined by the position of the element in the list.

Use [`nth-child` or `nth-of-type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#structural-pseudos) selectors in your stylesheet.

Comment: I think this is a smart guess, although unfortunately, I cannot use this technique, as that the order of the list is controlled not by their order in DOM, but an attribute using absolute position, so this technique won't work. But an educated guess and good answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have just tried wat u need just check it..

http://jsbin.com/awUWAMeN/7/edit

```
function change()
{
  var colors = ['green', 'red', 'purple'];
alert(colors)
$('.sd-list li').each(function(i) {
    var index = $(this).index();

        $(this).css('background-color', colors[index]);

});

}
```

Comment: Hi, this is actually not what I need. I am using the similar code, it's just that I have performance issue. But thanks anyway.

Comment: the list is about 5 - 7 items, the list can be reordered using dragging provided by gridster library, and item can be deleted which will also cause a recolor of each item below it

Answer (score 1):

I've created a simple test with 10 list items, each with 12 children and setting the background colour for every item each time Gridster's draggable.stop event fires. The change is pretty much instantaneous in IE11 and Chrome.

To me, this suggests it isn't the CSS rendering that's slow, but maybe the calculations determining which colours are for which elements.

This is the JavaScript I was using:

```
var colors = ['#000', '#001', '#002', '#003', '#004', '#005', '#006', '#007', '#008', '#009', '#00a', '#00b'];

$('.gridster ul').gridster({
    widget_margins: [10, 10],
    widget_base_dimensions: [120, 120],
    draggable: {
        stop: function (e, ui, $widget) {
            refreshListItemColor();
        }
    }
});

function refreshListItemColor() {
    var sortedElements = [];
    $('ul > li:not(.preview-holder').each(function () {
        sortedElements.push([this, this.getAttribute('data-col'), this.getAttribute('data-row')]);
    });

    sortedElements.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a[1] - b[1] || a[2] - b[2];
    });

    for (var i = sortedElements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sortedElements[i][0].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    }
}
```

How are you determining which colours to set on each list item?

Comment: The determination of the color is very simple, I have an color array with 7 items, and I use a simple index % 7 to determine which color to use, very simple and should not cause performance issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've find it fast to create a class with the css attributes you want and then add that class to the dom element you want the css attribute applied to. CSS rules appear without refresh.

css:

```
.bg-green{
background:green;
}
```

js:

```
$("#someDomId").toggleClass('bg-green','add');
```

A cool way of dealing with lists is to index the id of each list element as you create/alter it:

Create list:

```
for (i=0;i=m;i++){
var listElement = "<li id='"+i+">Some Content</div>";
$('ul').append(listElement);
}
```

Then instead of iterating through a dom element (which is expensive) you can run another for loop and alter each list element by selecting it's id.

```
for (i=0;i=m;i++){
$("#"+i).toggleClass('bg-green','add');
}
```